# How to cope with bidimensional data display AND edit

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, offset, point

I have to display double X,Y offset in a datagrid.
What is in my mind is something like (done with excel and photoshop):

[image]

allowing users to change offset value. Having also numbers printed on rows and columns.

At the moment the offset structure is:

```
 public Point[,] pointMatrix;
```

but when I associate it to the datagrid I get this error:

[image]

so perhaps a bidimensional array is not the right type.
Any hint about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't set the `ItemSource` of a `DataGrid` to a 2D array, you need to either bind it to a `List<List<Point>>` of to a `DataTable`, using a `DataTable` is much easier for you since it won't require much changes, add the following converter method that will convert a 2D array into a DataTable:

```
 private DataView ConvertFromMatrixToDataTable(Point[,] matrix)
    {

        var myDataTable = new DataTable();            
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {                
            var row = myDataTable.NewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                row[i] = matrix[i, j];
            }

            myDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return myDataTable.DefaultView;
    }
```

then use it to affect the `DataGrid`'s `ItemSource` :

```
dtgNests.ItemsSource = ConvertFromMatrixToDataTable(pointMatrix);
```